# Allow public access to controller action in WebForms + MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-authorization

I have a legacy ASP.Net web site into which I am integrating MVC.  I use webforms authentication with the standard authorization tag in web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I have been able to make various folders public in the past using locations such as:

```
<location path="Public">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

With the additional of MVC and a few controllers I have the need to make a few controller actions completely public.  However, I am unable to do this using the location tag in web.config.  If I attempt to go to an action's URL while not authenticated ASP.Net redirects me back to my login page (specified in web.config).  I am not using an Authorization attribute on any of these controller actions.

How do I open up access to these within breaking security to all the webforms, which do need protection?

Edit:

I want to make clear that I am using [Authorize] on actions I want protected.  The actions in questions, which I want made public, are not using the [Authorize] attribute and are still not accessible unless logged in.

Edit 2:

I have done some IIS traces and think I have convinced myself that this is indeed authentication failing, not some other error.  Here is an example of a location and route I am trying to access:

```
<location path="WC">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

And the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
          "WC", // Route name
          "WC/{id}",
          new { action = "GetWC", controller = "WC" } // URL with parameters
        );
```

And the URL that is failing:

```
http://localhost/MyWebApp/WC/42
```

I actually have a more generic route that handles this but added this to remove any doubt.  In any case this works fine with logged in.

Comment: Can you give an example of the location elements and routes you are trying? A mismatch between the two seems like the most likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use an ActionFilterAttribute to decorate certain methods as requiring authentication, while letting controller itself be publicly viewable, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`.  You can decorate either the controller class itself with it (which will cause all the action methods to be protected) or you can decorate the action method itself for finer grain control.

If neither are decorated, then they are callable by all users (including anonymous).  If you simply use `[Authorize]`, then only authorized users can call the action method.  You can also pass in a comma delimited list of roles to specify a list from which the user must have at least one of the roles in order to call the action method.

Comment: Then there is something else causing your issue.  By default, actions are public; it isn't until you decorate it (or its class) with Authorize that they become protected.  You may need to post various sections of your web.config to help us get you an answer (the authentication element, maybe any authorization elements you have).

Comment: Having researched this all day I have found statements contradicting this. From what I understand, OOB an MVC site is wide open but a WebForms site is not.  It looks like the difference is the authorization configuration in web.config.  I am thoroughly confused on this as so many people are saying things that contradict each other, including MVPs in the MS forums.

Comment: I've never had either a WebForms or MVC project be anything but wide open out of the box.  Nothing stops someone from creating their own project template though, so there could be some out there where they start off secured.

Comment: Right.  My point is that this is an existing WebForms project that already has UrlAuthorization configured, so URLs are locked down for I can even get to letting a controller's authorization via something like an IAuthorizationFilter ie Authorize attribute or controllers OnAuthorize.

Comment: Can you change your paths such that the MVC routing does not match the URLs for the various webforms pages?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your "Edit 2" section.  Can you post part of your WCController class (like the class declaration and the GetWC action declaration)?